# Query.list() returns empty list the first time, but not the second time

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

This is the scenario:

```
- Session 1 inserts a new object into the DB
- Session 2 immediately queries the new object from the DB using a HQL query
  -> first call to Query.list() (or Query.uniqueResult()) returns null
  -> second immediate call to Query.list() returns the new object
```

Is this a timing issue? Do I have to "wait" until the session 1 is "ready"? Is this a caching problem?

Using:
MS SQL Server 2014, Hibernate 4.1.1.Final

Maybe, relevant settings:
hibernate.connection.isolation=4096

Comment: Strange...does this happen intermittantly or always?

Comment: It is always reproducible within the application, but it is hard (for me) to extract a standalone code snippet.

Comment: One more note: hibernate.connection.isolation=4096

Comment: Could you post your code. Looks like two different instances of sessions. Did you save the data from first session.